# What are the best DI-IOC references for a vb.net programmer?

Tags: vb.net, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I code primarily in vb.net.  I've been doing basic dependency injection manually and am looking to learn more about DI/IoC and maybe use a DI/IoC framework/container like Ninject.  There are lots of examples and write-ups using Java and C# code.  I'm looking for the best resources for vb.net programmers.  Likewise, is there a particular framework that would be easiest for a vb.net programmer to pick up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [vb.net code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816062.aspx) for [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I do all my work in VB.NET and use [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) exclusively.

The biggest issue I've had when looking at other frameworks was the extensive use of Lambdas for the container configuration/registration.  Since VB.NET currently only supports  single line lambdas that return a value, i.e. Function(), it becomes unwieldy at best and  impossible in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I use [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/index.html) and made some posts about it

[StructureMap is way cool even in VB.Net](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/structuremap-is-way-cool-even-in-vb-net?highlight=structuremap&sentence=)

and the C# version

[Structuremap is way cool](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/structuremap-is-way-cool?highlight=structuremap&sentence=)

Mind you, the configuration has change a little since then.

But be aware that the current version (9.0) of VB.Net is not that good with lambda expressions. But this should be better with version 10.0

Comment: this seems to be the only suggestion for StructureMap here but none of these links seem to work...